# Optimizing performance: Google map via PHP, mySQL, and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, maps

Based on [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html) tutorial I have built a page which functions correctly. I added a couple of dropdown boxes to the page, and based on [this snippet](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/b53e0d9797ea8cb4), have been able to filter the results accordingly. So, in practice everything is working as it should. However, my question is regarding the efficiency of the proceedure. Right now, the process looks something like this:

1.) Users visits page
2.) Body onload() is called
3.) Javascript calls a PHP script, which queries the database (based on criteria passed along via the URL) and exports that query to an XML file.
4.) The XML file is then parsed via javascript on the users local machine.

For any one search there could be several thousand results (and thus, several thousand markers to place on the map). As you might have guessed, it takes a long time to place all of the markers. I have some ideas to speed it up, but wanted to touch base with experienced users to verify that my logic is sound. I'm open to any suggestions!

Idea #1: Is there a way (and would it speed things up?) to run the query once, generating an XML file via PHP which contained all possible results, store the XML file locally, then do the filtering via javascript?

Idea #2: Create a cron job on the server to export the XML file to a known location. Instead of using "Gdownloadurl(phpfile.php," I would use gdownloadurl(xmlfile.xml). Thus eliminating the need to run a new query every time the user changes the value of a drop down box

Idea #3: Instead of passing criteria back to the php file (via the URL) should I just be filtering the results via javascript before placing the marker on the map?

I have seen a lot of webpages that place tons and tons of markers on a google map and it doesn't take nearly as long as my application. What's the standard practice in a situation like this?

Thanks!

Edit: There may be a flaw in my logic: If I were to export all results to an XML file, how (other than javascript) could I then filter those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is sound, however, I probably wouldn't do the filtering in Javascript. If the user's computer is not very fast, then performance will be adversely affected. It is better to perform the filtering server side based on a cached resource (xml in your case).

The database is probably the biggest bottleneck in this operation, so caching the result would most likely speed your application up significantly. You might also consider you have setup your keys correctly to make your query as fast as possible.

Comment: I ended up changing the select query to only include the 8-10 columns needed, as opposed to the original select * which consisted of 300+ columns. Which did speed things up significantly.

However, the question remains though, how to go about caching the XML file? should I just run a script that saves the file to a publicly accessible folder? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Store the XML documents outside the document root, and have a PHP script that accepts parameters that it needs to filter against, and have your PHP script output the filtered XML document.

Comment: Thinking about it, you probably would be better off just storing the filtered versions of the query, based on a hash of the parameters given. That way, you will only suffer a performance penalty when fetching an uncached query, and subsequent requests can simply use the cached version (no filtering necessary). After all, 3k rows is not THAT significant of a performance hit (but should be avoided if possible).